# Can not figure out multithreading trouble in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a problem with my first experience in multithreading. I want to understand how it works, and so I try it on simple example, that I wrote.

So, there is class PaySystem:

```
    internal abstract class PaySystem
{
    public int payOperationTime;
    public readonly object _payLock = new object();

    public void Pay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There is a pay order in {0} pay system", GetType().Name);

        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_payLock))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} pay system is ready work, so we can start pay operation", GetType().Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} pay system is locked now by other pay operation, so we need to wait for end of last", GetType().Name);
        }

        lock (_payLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start pay operation on {0} pay sytem", GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine("payOperationTime for {0} paySystem will be {1}", GetType().Name, payOperationTime.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(payOperationTime);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Pay done by {0} pay system", GetType().Name);

    }
}
```

So, in my Main() method happens next:

```
        PayPal payPal = new PayPal();

        Thread payPalPayment = new Thread(payPal.Pay);
        Thread payPalPayment2 = new Thread(payPal.Pay);

        payPalPayment.Start();
        payPalPayment2.Start();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

And as output I have unpredictable(as for me) result. I attach printscreen of console output as file.

[image]

But, in few words, it looks like a second thread not continue Payment after first thread ends it.

If I understand correctly, I can start threads, and block that locked by locker will be executed/reached, when locker will be unlocked.

Can someone explain me what I do not understand or what I do not in the right way ?

**EDIT 1**

My question is: Why is second thread does not contines do payment ? The lines in the locked code block.

**EDIT 2. Answer**

I wanted to check if locker object is locked, and i used TryEnter() method.
As I figure it out with you help, dear stackoverflow audience, for my purpose I need to use IsEntered() method.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you first explain you question properly? I am having hard time getting it

Comment: Where is `PayPal` defined?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're expecting the code to do.  The first thread got the lock first, so it performed the operation within the lock.  By the time the second thread got to the lock, the first thread already had it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For check whether is object locked, It is need to use Monitor.IsEntered() method.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have got confused with Monitor.Enter and lock.

Monitor.TryEnter tries to obtain a lock on the object. If it succeeds, the object will remain locked until you do Monitor.Exit on it. Which you never do.

Lock is a shorthand for a Monitor.Enter followed by a Monitor.Exit (at the end of the block). The lock is all you really need - if you take the Monitor.TryEnter out, it will work as you expect.

Comment: Nikki is quite correct.  lock { } is useful for short ins-out when it comes to synchronizing threads.  However, if you need a threads to be able to "skip" a concurrent operation (by executing a TryEnter with a timeout), it's useful to use the Monitor.TryEnter() method to avoid blocking for long periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

You acquire the lock twice and only release it once, so you still hold the lock. If the call to `TryEnter` succeeds, the lock it acquires is never released, preventing the other thread from making forward progress.

Comment: `TryEnter` should be replaced with `IsEntered`. Edit: In Vladislav Hromyh original Pay() function.

Comment: @MrSykkox Why shouldn't it be `readonly`?  There's no reason the lock object should ever be changed, so making it `readonly` is a perfectly reasonable way to enforce that it won't be.

Comment: @SuperOli Yeah, this is the proper solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Monitor.TryEnter` + `Monitor.Exit` or just `Lock`.

`Lock` statement locks and releases the resource. `Monitor.TryEnter` only locks.